# Close Window for button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have been trying to close the window on button click but am unable to do so.

I have added javascript `window.close()`

added on the code behind page on button click event all in vain. Language `c#` or `vb.net`

Comment: People please! This person has not accepted any answers because nobody has answered his/her questions yet. While this is probably due at least in part to the fact that they're somewhat confusingly phrased, remember that not everybody was born speaking English.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That needs to be on the client side, try something like this:

```
<input type="button" id="close" onclick="window.close()" />
```

If you want an asp.net button you can do:

```
<asp:Button ID="close" runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript:window.close()" />
```

Although that would be a bit pointless. =)

Comment: Modern browsers prevent scripts from closing browser windows, unless the window was opened by a script. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/close).

Answer (score 4):

The button click event on the code behind only handles code that affects the server side. Closing a browser window is a client side action and must be called by something on the browser. This is usually done with an input button but can be used inside any kind of javascript event.

Here is an example that I pulled out of existing code, the extra calls were used for browser compatibility.

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.opener=null; window.close(); return false;" />
```

Also of note, browsers may block this action if it is not initiated by a user action.

Comment: Modern browsers prevent scripts from closing browser windows, unless the window was opened by a script. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/close).